# SOAP services using savon is not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have installed savon gem in windows 7 with ruby 1.8.
It shows in gem list

But when I give

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'savon'
```

It gives following error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Savon
        from ./savon.rb:3
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from (irb):1
```

any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your local file being named "savon.rb" might be conflicting with savon gem's file named "lib/savon.rb"

Comment: Ironically my file was also named savon.rb but this did not fix the problem.  I can run my savon test via the command line but I get the error from above when I run it via textmate.